# How to add units and text to legend of matrix image with R

Tags: r, image, matrix, legend

I have a matrix that I export in image and I would like to add units and text to my legend. Here my code:

```
library(imager)
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/R/")
#Export matrix as image in folder
jpeg(filename="result.jpeg", width=dim(image)[1], height=dim(image)[2])
image(result, useRaster=TRUE, axes=FALSE, col=c("grey",'yellow','green',"blue"))
grid(nx=(h), ny=(v), col="black", lty="solid")
legend("topleft", legend=c(A, B, C, D),
       col=c("grey",'yellow','green',"blue"), pch=15, bg='white',cex=1.5)
dev.off()
```

Here the picture I obtain:
[image]

How to add more detail on the legend as unit and text for each number in the legend ?

Comment: Could you make the example reproducible? We don't have access to `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start using `ggplot` to have more control over the plot image:

This requires you to alter the data format from a matrix to a long format. See this example

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyverse)


xsize <- 60
ysize <- 30

result <- matrix(sample(1:4,xsize*ysize,prob = c(.8,.1,.05,.05),replace = TRUE),
                 nrow = ysize)


result %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(y = row_number()) %>%
  gather(x, value,-y) %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(str_extract(x,'[0-9]+'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x,y=y, fill = factor(value,labels = c("A","B","C","something else")))) +
  labs(fill = "Your legend name here") +
  geom_tile(color = "black")
```

[image]